# is it possible to get remote ip by apache run in docker

Tags: docker, apache2

I have create a apache server in docker, but the ip what i get in access log is just from my docker ip, not from remote client ip.

Is it possible to get remote ip?

I have try to use mod_remoteip and it is not works.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile or docker run commands to start apache? I've tested on my apache image and I can see external IP addresses in my access log.

Comment: docker run -it -p 90:80 image_id bash

Answer (score -2):

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# make sure the package repository is up to date and update ubuntu
RUN locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl lsb-release supervisor openssh-server libapache2-mod-passenger git apache2  vim


# supervisor installation &&
# create directory for child images to store configuration in
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor && \
mkdir -p /var/run/sshd && \
mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor && \
mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d


# default command
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: after i run the docker i just get following apache log: 172.17.42.1 - - [24/Sep/2015:15:42:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [24/Sep/2015:15:42:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [24/Sep/2015:15:42:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
172.17.42.1 - - [24/Sep/2015:15:42:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11764 "-" "curl/7.35.0"